# Standard Brownian Motion and Exponential Martingale calculation

Tags: brownian-motion, martingale

Let $W(t)$ be a standard brownian motion and let $Z(t) = \exp (\lambda W(t) - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2 t).$ In Xinfeng Zhou's Green Book in the section on Brownian Motion (p.130) he writes as part of the proof that $Z(t)$ is a martingale, that $$\mathbb{E}[Z(t+s)]=\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda(W(t)+W(s)) - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2 (t+s))] $$ My question is how does he go from $Z(t+s) = \exp (\lambda W(t+s) - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2 (t+s))$ to $W(t)+W(s)$ in the exponent ? Thanks for clearing up my confusion, I am just getting into Brownian Motions and Stochastic Calculus.

Comment: This equation is wrong. $\mathbb E[Z(t+s)]=1$ and the right hand side is not one because $W(t)$ and $W(s)$ have covariance $s$.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks, then there must be a mistake in the book.

Comment: I won't share the pdf of it that I found but someone striked out by hand the term $W(t)+W(s)$ and replaced it with the correct $W(t+s)$. A typo obviously.

Comment: It gets worse: Zhou "proves" on that p. 130 after a few further manipulations that $\mathbb E[Z(t+s)]=Z_t$ which is only correct for $t=0\,.$ A dubious book when it comes to stochastic calculus.

Comment: @KurtG. Agreed, I was trying to make it make sense, thinking the author's approach would have to be right but my level wasn't sufficient to point out the exact mistakes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z$ is a martingale, indeed. It is easily proved using Itō's lemma (the drift disappears and the diffusion term is constant, hence square-integrable on any compact). Another way to see it is
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left[Z \left(s\right) \middle \vert \mathcal{F}_t\right] & = \mathbb{E} \left[Z \left(s\right) \middle \vert W \left(t\right)\right]
\\
& =\mathbb{E} \left[e^{\lambda W \left(t\right) - \frac{1}{2} \lambda^2 t + \lambda \left[W
\left(s\right) - W \left(t\right)\right] - \frac{1}{2} \lambda^2 \left(s
- t\right)}\middle \vert W \left(t\right)\right] \\
& = Z \left(t\right) e^{- \frac{1}{2} \lambda^2 \left(s
- t\right)} \mathbb{E} \left[e^{\lambda \left[W
\left(s\right) - W \left(t\right)\right]} \middle \vert W \left(t\right)
\right]
\end{align}
From the Markov property of Brownian motion and its centered Gaussian distribution, the conditional expectation is equal to $e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda^2 \left(s
- t\right)}$ and therefore
$$
\boxed{\mathbb{E} \left[Z \left(s\right) \middle \vert \mathcal{F}_t\right] = Z \left(t\right)}
$$
which is the definition of a martingale.